# How to block all incoming proxy visits except from one specific I.P?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy, ip

I have a page that is prone to attacks, so, in order to reduce the anonymous attacks, I use this code in my **.htaccess** which I found online :

```
# BLOCK PROXY VISITS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

My problem is that one advertiser uses proxies inside his company and thus cannot visit my page. I have no idea on regular expressions, even though I think i can *recognize* one when I see it, as in "oh, look a regex". I think the conditions above are regexes, but I do not have the knowledge to alter them in a way, that only the proxy visits from this specific static IP are not banned.

How do I achieve that if possible? Thank you in advance!

**Edit :** As suggested i took this question at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/499803/how-to-block-all-incoming-proxy-visits-except-from-one-specific-i-p). Follow this link for more.

Comment: I think this is better suited for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this customer has always the same specific IP, you can detect this with a [`RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and stop any further rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

# new rule
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =1.2.3.4
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# old proxy rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
...
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

You must put this rule at the beginning, because otherwise the other rule will reject the request. The first rule allows the IP 1.2.3.4 to see your website and the second rule blocks as before. All other clients are not affected and can see everything as before.

Comment: I am going to try this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I must add the two lines right after RewriteEngine on and leave the other ones too? 

What I did was, added the {REMOTE_ADDR} line as first in the conditional stack, commented the old rewrite rule and then, added the new one. That resulted in an internal server error.